# Find & replace bold, italic and underline text in Richtext box in VB

Tags: vb.net

I need to find bold , italic, underline Text, paragraph  and line breaks in VB Rich Text box and replace the find result with the following :

Bold text with '< b >bold text < / b >'

Italic text with "< i >Italic text < / i >"

Underline text '< u >underline text < / u >'

Paragraph with '< p >paragraph text< / p >'

line break with '< / br >'

Can any one help on this? I am new to Vb.

Thanks in Advance